# Add-WindowsFeature fails with unexpected path

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, powershell

The following error is occurring running Add-WindowsFeature:

```
PS C:\Users\pornograph> Add-WindowsFeature -Name "DSC-Service" -IncludeAllSubFeature -ErrorVariable errorVar
Add-WindowsFeature : The request to list features available on the specified server failed.
A DISM session could not be opened.
An error occurred. The directory in the temporary folder D:\TEMP\ could not be created.
Ensure that the path to the temporary folder exists and that you have Read/Write permissions on the folder. Error:
0x80070003
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-WindowsFeature -Name "DSC-Service" -IncludeAllSubFeature -ErrorVariable erro ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (@{Vhd=; Credent...Name=localhost}:PSObject) [Install-WindowsFeature],DeploymentProviderException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DISMAPI_Error__Failed_Opening_Dism_Session,Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.AddWindowsFeatureCommand
```

Where is `D:\TEMP\` coming from?

- Server has no D:
- No environment variable starts with D:

  - Machine `TEMP` and `TMP` = `E:\TEMP`
  - User and Process `TEMP` and `TMP` = `C:\Users\etc.`
- OS = Win 2012 R2 Standard x64
- $psversiontable.psversion = `4 0 -1 -1`

Comment: Have you tried searching the registry for ``D:\TEMP\``?

Comment: I would use Dism.exe directly and then check the dism logs.

Comment: I notice you aren't running Powershell as Administrator. Do you get the same error if you do Run as Administrator?

Comment: DISM will be running as Local System at the point of failure, and I have a unsubstantiated feeling that somehow you've got a temp variable incorrectly set.  You can try starting an interactive cmd session with the `psexec` tool, and then dumping the environment variables.  PSExec is available at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec, and `psexec -i -d -s cmd` will start an interactive command prompt. You can use `whoami` to ensure you're running under the right context, then `set` to check the variables.  If those show D:, it'll narrow things.

Answer (score 0):

(Edit to original question seems to be stuck in moderation, so here it is again:)

UPDATE: It appears to be in the registry (most likely set in the original server image):

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\Packages\Microsoft-PowerShell-DSC-PullServer-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~en-US~6.3.9600.16384`

`InstallLocation` = `"\\?\D:\temp\Dism\IDASF2ZC\{GUID}\"`

The entire `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing` tree is owned by TrustedInstaller (all others = read only). Granting write and changing the value seemed to make no change (`D:\TEMP` still being used) - does something need to be restarted for the new value to be read?

Running as admin is not an option unfortunately.